# How to increment a data field in Firestore using Firebase Modular SDK V9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to increment data for sending a num to other user's num.

```
const sendNum = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        
        const targetQuery = query(userCol, where("keycode", "==", parseInt(target)));
        const targetSnapshot = await getDocs(targetQuery)
        
        targetSnapshot.forEach((document) => {
            console.log(document.data().num)
            console.log(document.id)
            const targetRef = doc(db, 'users', document.id)

            setDoc(targetRef, {
                num: // increment user data here
            }, {merge: true})
        })
}
```

But a documentation that I found, I don't really understand them.
And the one I understand, it's already outdated.
So I would be very happy if anyone know how :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation has a dedicated section for that called [increment a numeric value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value).

```
import { setDoc, increment } from "firebase/firestore";

await setDoc(targetRef, {
    num: increment(50)
});
```

You cannot use `await` in a `forEach` loop (`setDoc` returns a promise and must be awaited) so try using either [`Batch Writes`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) or [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

[Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)